# SELECT INTO WITH NOT NULL constraint Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am creating a new table dos3 from dos using SELECT INTO in Redshift. However, while location_code is a primary key (NOT NULL) in table dos, after performing the SELECT INTO operation, the new table is converting it into a NULLABLE field.

Alter Column SET NOT NULL is also not supported. How to achieve this?

```
SELECT
 location_code, item_no
INTO analytics.dos3 
FROM analytics.dos
WHERE date>'2020-10-20'
```

My table dos is huge and I want to add a few columns in beginning of table from another table join. Hence using this approach. The joined query I have not added in the question as it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are hitting the first of many limitations of "select into" and you will want to investigate if this is really that route you want to go down in this use case.  Let me try to lay out some of the concerns I see.

First off "select into" is not very rich in terms of setting target table attributes as you are finding.  CTAS (create table as) has more features such as setting of table distribution and sort keys which is why it is generally favored over "select into".  You say that the resulting table is going to be added to and become very large - having keys on the table will be a good idea.  CTAS is also higher performance when the amount of data being moved is large.  But even CTAS will not give you the per-column definitions you want (and others you will likely need when this table expands).

Some other considerations - Since you are adding a lot of data after this table is created, you will want to be sure that this large amount of data will fit in the column definitions.  Will the varchars be large enough?  Will the numerics be the right size? etc.  You will want to set keys on the table - dist, sort, primary etc. - to get the best performance.  Column encodings can help too.  It is also important to make sure that varchar columns are not max size (64k) for large tables - While having large varchars doesn't impact disk storage, they do impact memory utilization during querying. When this table gets very large this can be a performance killer.

All in all - very large tables need to be thought about more that "just create it from a select into".  You will want to create the optimal table definition and then insert your data into it. (I'll get off my soapbox now)

If you still want to go down this path you can set this column attribute after the fact (sort of).  It just takes a 4 step process.  1) add another column with the desired attributes using "alter table".  2) update this new column with the data from the one made by "select into". 3) delete the original column from the table. 4) rename the new column the same as the original using "alter table".  This can be done for any number of columns. Sure seems easier to me to just make the right table in the first place.

PS. remember that Redshift doesn't enforce uniqueness on primary keys - it is the responsibility of the user to do this.  Since you are doing multiple inserts into the new table you will want to make sure there is no duplicates if this is really a PK.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Just realised the limitations of Redshift after spending half a day in trying to achieve this. Finally after trying INSERT INTO SELECT etc (to retain nullable) I realised none of this is scalable and  went down the S3 COPY path

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, select into will not bring the not null to the new table. Create your table explicitly with the list of columns, data types and distribution key etc... and then run an insert into ..select list.  Then rename the tables at the end, this is the fastest way to do it.

Adding additional columns, updating them & dropping the old columns is a very resource intensive process and could run long time depending on the amount of data you have in your table.